# text-decoration-thickness in Chrome / Opera

Tags: css

I style an underline with the following code:

```
text-decoration: underline;
text-decoration-thickness: 1.5px;
text-underline-offset: 3px;
text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
```

Unfortunately, as of now, this only works in Safari and Firefox. – What would be an elegant way of doing this, so that it also works in other common browsers like Chrome, or Opera?

Comment: Use _-webkit-_ before adding the style. Webkit works for Google Chrome, Safari, Android Browser. And use _-o-_ for Opera. Consider reading this: https://bitsofco.de/css-vendor-prefixes/

Comment: @Soban Unfortunately, in this case, this doesn't work…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `border-bottom` property for supporting all browser instead of `text-decoration-thickness`.